# How to create an .Xresource file in home directory?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-20.04, xterm

I want to change appearance of xterm terminal. I came to knew that for that we have to create an . Xresource file in home directory and merge using the command

xrdb -merge ~/. Xresource

Can anyone help me know how create a .Xresource file in home directory? I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a better fit for askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate file is `.Xdefaults` usually with a dash and the hostname appended due to a conflicting usage versus xrdb.

For example

```
$ hostname
nosuchhost
$ ls -a .Xdefa*
.Xdefaults-nosuchhost
```

See [mailing list discussion](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/vile/2019-11/msg00003.html) on this (the manual page is inadequate).